# Joomla/IIS7 url rewrite not showing Joomla Template

Tags: iis-7, joomla, url-rewriting

I have an issue where the URL re-write in IIS7 loads the component contents just fine, but not the site template.

Where this:

http://125valleywood.nexthometown.com/

Should look like this:

http://www.nexthometown.com/index.php?option=com_singleprop&view=singleprop&mlsnum=4200072

If I use "redirect" instead of "rewrite" everything is fine.  I figure it has something to do with the domain joomla is tied to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to not use URL re-write.  I instead mimicked a blind URL redirect using the DNS manager on windows server 2008.  I figure it had something to do with the Joomla install not recognizing the subdomain.  What I did not look into was seeing if Joomla would take a wildcard for the sitename, ie `*.mysite.com`.  But since I never determined whether or not this was the problem in the first place, I not sure this would have been a solution.